# metric_fu equivalent for ruby 1.9.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, metric-fu

[metric](https://github.com/jscruggs/metric_fu)_fu doesn't seem to be supported in the latest ruby kernel (1.9.2 | 1.9.3). Are there any gems which offer equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [Metrical](https://github.com/iain/metrical), last time I looked it still wasn't 100% but that was months ago.

Comment: as of 2012-04-26, the readme states that it is no longer being maintained saying "Warning: This gem is not being maintained anymore!"

Answer (score 3):

I'm the new maintainer of metric_fu and it should work now on ruby 1.9 without any problems. See configuration instructions at https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu which include how you can have metric_fu load external coverage output (e.g. using simplecov)

Also, it works from the command-line now. Now need to bundle it or run rake or metrical

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2 metrics post](http://www.noletterword.com/blog/?p=695) by STEPAN BOLTALIN looks promising.  His Roodi explanation may be key to it all.